# If $f(z)$ is meromorphic but not entire, is $\exp(f(z))$ meromorphic? Could it even be entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, analyticity, singularity-theory

First, I can show that $f$ meromorphic is a rational function.  Now, I want to consider $g=e^{f(z)}$.

I have heard that there is something interesting that goes on with $g$, that there is some room for interpretation.

Of course, the quick answer would be "no, where $f$ has a pole, $g$ would have infinitely many negative power terms in $(z-z_0)$ in its Laurent expansion, and by definition $g$ has an essentially singularity there and hence cannot be meromorphic."

Are there conditions that would *make* $g$ meromorphic?  Even entire?

$f$ is only assumed to be meromorphic but not entire.

Thanks,

Comment: What makes you doubt the quick answer you give yourself? If $f$ has any poles, then they will correspond to essential singularities of $g$, there's no way around that. So a condition that makes $g$ meromorphic _has to_ prevent $f$ from having poles -- and if we already know $f$ is meromorphic this means that the condition has to be that $f$ is actually entire.

Comment: now you can prove that if $g(z)$ is holomorphic around $0$ and $f(z)$ is meromorphic around $0$, then $g(f(z))$ is holomorphic around $0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is itself holomorphic around $0$.

Comment: Right @user1952009 ... subtracting off the principal parts of $f(z)$, including the principal parts corresponding to any poles that $f$ has at infinity, e.g., also subtracting off the terms $z + z^2 + ... z^n$, this makes $f$ pole-free and meromorphic around 0, and in turn makes $g$ meromorphic.  Is this what you are trying to convey?  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has a pole at a point $a$.  Then the function $h(z)=1/f(z)$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $a$ with $h(a)=0$.  By the open mapping theorem, if $B$ is any ball around $a$, then $h(B)$ contains a ball around $0$.  It follows that there exists an $R>0$ such that $f(z)$ takes all values of modulus $>R$ on $B$.  In particular, by the $2\pi i$-periodicity of $\exp$, $g(z)=\exp(f(z))$ takes *every* value other than $0$ on $B$ (since for any nonzero value, we can find a logarithm of it with imaginary part $>R$).

That is, $g$ takes every value except $0$ in every neighborhood of $a$.  It follows that $a$ must be an essential singularity of $g$.  So if $f$ has poles, $g$ must have essential singularities, and hence cannot be meromorphic.